# UnicodeWarning While Using Dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, encryption, unicode, ascii

I've been playing with Python 2.7 for a while, and I'm now tryin to make my own Encryption/Decryption algorithm.
I'm trying to make it support non-Ascii characters.
So this is a part of the dictionnary :

```
... u'\xe6': '1101100', 'i': '0001000', u'\xea': '1100001', 'm': '0001100', u'\xee': '1100111', 'q': '0010000', 'u': '0010100', u'\xf6': '1110010', 'y': '0011000', '}': '1001111'}
```

But when I try to convert, by exemple, "é" into binairy, doing

```
 base64 = encrypt[i]
```

where as encrypt is the name of the dic and i = u"é"

I get this error :

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "D:\DeskTop 2\Programs\Projects\4.py", line 174
    base64 = encrypt[i]
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DeskTop 2\Programs\Projects\4.py", line 197, in 
    main()
  File "D:\DeskTop 2\Programs\Projects\4.py", line 196, in main
    decryption(key, encrypt, decrypt)
  File "D:\DeskTop 2\Programs\Projects\4.py", line 174, in decryption
    base64 = encrypt[i]
KeyError: '\xf1'

Also, I did start with

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-*-
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, sorry for the useless post.
I found the fix. Basically, I did :

```
for i in user_input:
    base64 = encrypt[i]
```

but i would be like \0xe

I added

```
j = i.decode("latin-1")
```

so j = u"\0xe"
And now it works :D